# What are the default mouse settings on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

What are the default mouse settings on Windows 10?  In particular I'm interested in knowing about the number of lines for vertical scrolling, but this is really asking about all these settings in general.  If there's a good way to reset these settings - which I would expect - that would be fine too.

Everything on Google seems to only describe how to change the settings, not what the defaults are or how to reset them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, I assume that manufacturers can(and sometimes do) override default settings.

That being said, on the three unaltered (default set-up) systems I've checked running Windows 10 the settings are as follows:

---

Mouse

```
Primary Button:              Left

Mouse Wheel Scrolls:         Multiple lines at a time (as opposed to a screen at a time)

How many lines to scroll:    3

Inactive window scroll:      On
```

---

These are all of the settings that are in the literal "settings" area of Windows 10. Under the control panel you can gain access to more mouse settings, for instance I have a specific driver downloaded for the Comfort Optical Mouse 3000 by Microsoft. You will also find settings separated into tabs for Buttons, Pointers, Pointer Options, Wheel, Hardware, and any device specific driver should be represented by a tab here as well.

---

Buttons

```
Configuration:           Right-handed

Double Click Speed:      . . . . . . | . . . .   (5th notch from the right) 

Click Lock:              Off
```

---

Pointers

```
Scheme:                  (None)

Enable pointer shadow:   Off
```

---

Pointer Options

```
Pointer Speed:                   . . . . . | . . . . .   (Dead center notch)

Enhance pointer precision:       On

Snap To:                         Off

Display pointer trails:          Off

Hide pointer while typing:       On

Show pointer location on CTRL:   Off
```

---

Wheel

```
Vertical Scrolling:    3 lines

Horizontal Scrolling:  3 characters (if you have a device supporting horizontal scrolling)
```

---

Hardware settings and Driver tabs are completely dependent on the devices(mice) you use and drivers you download.

Answer (score 3):

**Defaults**

- Vertical Scrolling is 3
- Horizontal Scrolling is 3

**Registry File**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"WheelScrollChars"="3"
"WheelScrollLines"="3"
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 and remembered to export all the defaults from the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse]
"ActiveWindowTracking"=dword:00000000
"Beep"="No"
"DoubleClickHeight"="4"
"DoubleClickSpeed"="500"
"DoubleClickWidth"="4"
"ExtendedSounds"="No"
"MouseHoverHeight"="4"
"MouseHoverTime"="400"
"MouseHoverWidth"="4"
"MouseSensitivity"="10"
"MouseSpeed"="1"
"MouseThreshold1"="6"
"MouseThreshold2"="10"
"MouseTrails"="0"
"SmoothMouseXCurve"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,15,6e,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,29,dc,03,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,28,00,00,00,00,00
"SmoothMouseYCurve"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,11,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,24,\
  04,00,00,00,00,00,00,fc,12,00,00,00,00,00,00,c0,bb,01,00,00,00,00
"SnapToDefaultButton"="0"
"SwapMouseButtons"="0"
```

You can save this into a `.reg` file to import it or just manually change the ones you want via `regedit`.